# Visual Studio 2013. Панель компонентов

Tags: visual-studio

Закрыл панель компонентов для формы (Кнопки, Списки etc). Где она находится?

Answer (score 1):

`View/Toolbox`. Выяснил когда удалил :

> \Users[username]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0